# Artifacts in gdalwarp output (from polar stereographic to azimuthal equidistant)

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, azimuth

I'm trying to warp some GeoTIFF images ([from NSIDC](http://nsidc.org/data/docs/noaa/g02135_seaice_index/)), from a polar stereographic projection, to an azimuthal equidistant projection using `gdalwarp`:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs 'EPSG:102016' \
  -te -7000000 -7000000 7000000 7000000 \
  input.tif output.tif
```

The result looks fine overall, except for a single horizontal row of pixels in the middle that looks "shifted" inward toward the center.

Is there any way to avoid this?

[image: output image from gdalwarp (converted to gif)]

---

Edit: Input image (as a gif) for reference

[image: image credit: NISDC]

Comment: can we see input.tif ?

Comment: did you try another  resampling_method than the default one ?
like bilinear ressampling : ```gdalwarp -t_srs 'EPSG:102016' \
  -te -7000000 -7000000 7000000 7000000 \ -r bilinear
  input.tif output.tif ```

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa I did - however, I'm looking to do some more processing (color substitution) in other software, so I'd rather keep it aliased until all that's done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest trying to add the `-et` (error threshold) option with a lower thresholds than the default.

If you try a lower -et threshold the horizontal artifact should disappear

Or try changing the re-sampling

`gdalwarp -r mode`

As a reference [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'd overlooked the -et option. Setting it all the way to zero did the trick (I first tried a few orders of magnitude below the default, but the artefact stuck around until I just fed it zero). And yes, different resampling would likely have fixed it too, but for later image processing purposes, I prefer to keep it aliased for now